# Injecting a class that is in other assembly using ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, portable-areas

My project is done using portable areas, I’m using ninject for DI, I’m injecting a class that is in other assembly, so I have this code in the areaRegistraction:

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IModuleManager>().Add(this.module);  
IKernel kernel = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IKernel>();  
kernel.Bind<IConfigurationRepository>().To<ConfigurationRepository>();
```

In my constructor I have this code:

```
public RequestController(IconfigurationRepository configurationRepository)
{
    this.configurationRepository= configurationRepository;
}
```

But by some reason configurationRepository is null

But if I put:

```
public RequestController()
{
   this.configurationRepository = ((StandardKernel)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IKernel>()).GetAll<IConfigurationRepository>().First();
}
```

It works fine.  What is the different between them?

Any clue will be really appreciated.

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work? Does it give you a two-week notice or what?

Comment: I updated my question. The problem is that configurationRepository is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second implementation will work if several `IConfigurationRepository` are registered but the first one will fail in this case.

What's the exception in the first case? What happens if you use `Single` instead of `First` in the second case?

Comment: In first case configurationRepository is null. If i use single

Comment: If i use single instead of First in the second, give it exception:Sequence contains more than one element.

Comment: There you have the problem. Ninject does not allow having multiple bindings because it would be ambiguous which one to take.